# Sql - Returning row numbers

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, greatest-n-per-group

I have a query I am running on 2 tables. The child table corresponds to the parent table.

In other words there are 6 entries in the parent table.

For each of these 6 entries there is a foreign key that returns 1000's of records.

I need to return the first 25 records for EACH of the 6 entries.

I am able to return the first 150 records but not by their id.

`select * from table where rownum <150`

But this obviously doesn't return the first 25 entries for EACH.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What RDBMS and which version are you using?

Comment: @Bill Would you care to tell us the RDBMS you are using? What database, dude?

Comment: Oracle 10g. Using Hibernate so probably need to write HQL once I complete this first step.

Comment: Make sure you accept one of these answers, so that people will answer your questions in the future.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming an RDBMS that supports window functions:

```
SELECT q.parent_column_a, q.child_column_b
    FROM (SELECT p.column_a AS parent_column_a, c.column_b AS child_column_b,
                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY p.primarykey ORDER BY c.primarykey) AS RowNum
              FROM parent p
                  INNER JOIN child c
                      ON p.primarykey = c.foreignkey) q
    WHERE q.RowNum <= 25
```

Comment: I totally posted seconds before you did :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL Server or Oracle, this is the solution.

```
select * from
(
    select p.parent_id, c.child_id, 
    row_number() over (partition by c.parent_id order by c.child_id) rn
    from parent p inner join child c on p.parent_id = c.parent_id
) subsel
where rn <= 25
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 25 SubEntries.SubEntryID
FROM Entries Entries
INNER JOIN SubEntries SubEntries
   ON Entries.EntryID = SubEntries.EntryID
```

Comment: -1 That's not what OP needs: "I need to return the first 25 records for EACH of the 6 entries"

Comment: Are the entries static/non-changing, like an enumerated list or something? If so, you could get the top 25 of each entry and use UNION to join the results into one result set.

Comment: Entries are static. So for each of the 6 records, I need to retrieve the first 25 records so I can populate into my object.

Comment: Table 1 - A, B, C, D, E, F. Table 2 - Entries each correspond with foreign key. Now for each of the records in Table 1, need to return the first 25 records in table 2.  From this I can populate my objects.

Answer (score 0):

This works on my data

**Explanation**

Basically, you use a WHERE clause to select only those rows where the child table id is in the top 25 of all rows in the child table that correspond to its parent.

**Query**

```
SELECT * -- Column List
FROM ParentTable
    INNER JOIN SubTable
WHERE SubTable.ID IN 
    (SELECT TOP 25 SubTable.ID 
     FROM SubTable s2 
     WHERE s2.ParentTableID = SubTable.ParentTableID)
```

*This should work on virtually any sql database.*